# jQuery - autocomplete : use the same code for multiple inputfields

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm new here and I have a question:

html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text" id="eenheid" class="form-control autocomplete-field" name="eenheid" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Eenheid..."></div><div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text" id="ingredient" class="form-control autocomplete-field" name="ingredient" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ingredient...">
```

jQuery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//autocomplete
var autocomplete_field_id = $('.autocomplete-field').attr('id');

$(".autocomplete-field").on('input', function() {
    autocomplete_field_id = this.id;
});

$( "#" + autocomplete_field_id ).autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete.php?field=" + autocomplete_field_id,
    minLength: 2
 });
});
```

I'm trying to use the same code for multiple inputfields, when a inputfield is active the jQuery selector from the autocomplete function should change to the id from the active inputfield.

With the code I currently use the selector (id) always stays the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly, you want the value of the selector `autocomplete_field_id` to be the id of the active input field.

Instead of using `on('input')`, you should use `on('focus')`.

You can write your code this way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //autocomplete
    var autocomplete_field_id;

    $(".autocomplete-field").on('focus', function() {
        autocomplete_field_id = this.id;
    });

    $( "#" + autocomplete_field_id ).autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php?field=" + autocomplete_field_id,
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you what you want is to add the same autocomplete to each input you can use jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) -

```js
//autocomplete
$(".autocomplete-field").each(function(index, me) {
  // me referrs to the current item with class "autocomplete-field"
  $(me).autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete.php?field=" + autocomplete_field_id,
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

[`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) will cycle through every element that matches the selector and run the provided function (in this case you're adding an auto complete).
The parameters represent -

- The index of the item within the selected set ("index")
- The item itself ("me")